# Android create second database after first database is created

Tags: android, sqlite

So I created first database, and now I need to create separate database, zipped it and send it to server.

I'm just wondering if it is doable?

And how can I do it?

Comment: So you created a sqlite database in your app, now you want to create another one, export it, and send it to a server. Are the two databases related at all?

Comment: @Ethan no, but I will write parcel data from db1 to db2. Also I want to destroy db2 after sent to server.

Comment: So you don't want to create a separate database....you just want to pull some data from db1 and send it to the server.

Comment: However, the file type has to be SQLite

Comment: Okay, so run your query(s) to get the data you want from db1, create db2, insert everything from your query(s) to db1 into db2 via the Cursor's you get back, then get the path to db2 (there's a getPath() method on database) and then send that file. Then delete db2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am going to do and want to do. 

But how can I create db2? and giving specific path

Comment: You said you created the first db so I assumed you knew how. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Wait, so when you say you "created first database" do you mean you created it in Android or that you have a sqlite file....

Comment: created it in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic logic of what you want to do, it'll have to be supplemented with specific code from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

and here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

and here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html

```
SQLiteDatabase database1 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(<PATH TO DATABASE1>, null, 0);
SQLiteDatabase database2 = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(<WHEREVER YOU WANT DATABASE2 TO GO>, null);
Cursor cursor = database1.query(<You'll really just have to fill this in with what you're pulling from database1, it's way too specific>);
ContentValues contentValues;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(<Column key>, <Column value from cursor>)
    // I.E. contentValues.put(ID_KEY, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID_KEY));
    // <INSERT THE REST OF YOUR COLUMNS INTO contentValues>
    database2.insert(<TABLE_NAME>, null, contentValues);
}

cursor.close();
database1.close();
database2.close();
```

To send it, that depends on way too many things for me to address. You have the database file now, send it using whatever protocol you please. If you don't know how to do this, search for "Android send File to Server" (try with an without quotes).

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful!! I got the sending part cover.

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)